# Trello API Docs not specific

Tags: trello, api

What are the possible values for the [`oneTimeMessagesDismissed` property](https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#post-1-members-idmember-or-username-onetimemessagesdismissed) of the Member object returned from the Trello API?  Through downloading the data of my own account, I see `BoardsListBC`, but I don't understand what that translates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That route is not intended to be documented, and will disappear from the documentation in the near future.  We do not intend for third parties to use it; it is data specific to the official web client that doesn't really mean anything outside of that context.

Comment: Awesome... I guess I'll remove it from Manatee.Trello now...  Thanks.